# Huge image over many pages

Tags: graphics

I have around 50 images of hand written notes like the one below. I want to merge them together in a PDF. How can I do that, so that each Image is distributed over many pages, while keeping its size? So, it should not be a document with 50 gigantic pages but instead one document with the necessary amount of pages with standard size.

[image].

Comment: I take it you want to crop and combine pages.  It's not that hard to do manually using \includegraphics (graphicx package).  Slightly more complicated if you want to overlap the margins.

Comment: The `\includegraphics` commands have option to [clip the output of the images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237201/11604) without touching the source images, but you will finish before splitting up the source images (with Gimp, for instance) to pieces of  width to height ratio similar to A4 pages, and  then  include each image as is, setting only the width or height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify the textheight by setting the margins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,multido}
\parindent=0pt
\newsavebox\IBox \sbox\IBox{\includegraphics{/tmp/V43SK}}
\begin{document}
\offinterlineskip    
\multido{\iA=0+1,\iB=1+1}{9}{%
  \includegraphics[
    trim=0 \dimexpr\ht\IBox-\iB\textheight\relax{} 0 \iA\textheight,
    clip,width=\textwidth]{/tmp/V43SK}\newline}

\end{document}
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: is there a way to find the amount of repetitions needed?

Comment: `\ht\IBox` is the height and divided by `\textheight`  the number of pages